# alternative to finding an <img> x and y origin

Tags: javascript

I have the following js which is basically to find the x and y origin of the top left of the  tag. This however, doesn't always work, for some reason, and some times it work. Not sure why, but some of the offsetLeft and offsetTop are 0. Do you have any other alternative to this?

```
function f() {
  var el = document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f);
  var pos = [el.offsetLeft, el.offsetTop];
  var parent = el.offsetParent;
  if (parent != el) {
    while (parent) {
      pos[0] += parent.offsetLeft;
      pos[1] += parent.offsetTop;
      parent = parent.offsetParent;
    }
  }
  return pos.toString();
} f();
```

I am also trying to get the width and height of the image by doing element.clientWidth and element.clientHeight. Why is this giving me 0 as well?

Comment: Can you paste a jsfiddle that shows it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Problem, I think you missed the offset of the node itself.

This function I wrote I use often.
Try it out and tell me the scenario where it doesn't work...

```
    /**
     * Returns an Object with an x and an y value giving the current top and
     * left of the DOM element.
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement}
     *          element
     * @return
     * @type Object
     */
    function getElementPosition(node) {
        try {
            var xy = {
                x : 0,
                y : 0
            };
            var parent = node.offsetParent;
            while (parent) {
                xy.x += parent.offsetLeft;
                xy.y += parent.offsetTop;
                parent = parent.offsetParent;
            }
            xy.x += node.offsetLeft;
            xy.y += node.offsetTop;
            return xy;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("getElementPosition(", arguments, ") >", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added some comments that clientWidth and clientHeight is also 0 for this img, wonder why?

Comment: When do you call the function? on which event?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but I think you might want to look into `getBoundingClientRect()`

EDIT this gets the position relative to the viewport to you need to control for scrolling. EG:

```
myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY
myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.scrollX
```

more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect